# git - preserve a specific file in repo when pushing

Tags: git, github

I want to preserve a file in repo when pushing.

**Local directory**

```
Dir
----file_1.css
----file_2.css
----file_3.css
----.gitignore
```

**Github repo**

```
repo
----file_1.css
----file_2.css
----file_3.css
----preserve.css
----.gitignore
```

My local directory does not have `preserve.css` file. So when I commit and push, `preserve.css` file is deleted in my repo. However, I want to keep `preserve.css` in my repo even if it's not present in my local directory.

For personal reason, I want it to be present only in my github repo, and want to edit & save it online only in repo. But making changes in the local directory and pushing prevents me from doing so.

I tried adding `preserve.css` in `.gitignore` file in local directory, but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you commit the deletion?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i've never deleted `preserve.css` because I never created it in my local repo at all. Everything about `preserve.css` was done in my github repo

Comment: Have you pulled those changes? Git will only delete a file that was added by “adding its deletion”. So if it never existed in your local repo, commiting should not delete it from the github.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the local repo is a clone of the remote one, Git compares the contents of your local and remote repo to decide what changes have been done. You can see those changes with `git status`.

In order not to 'commit' the deletion of the file you have to unstage it with `git reset HEAD preserve.css` or not stage the file at all.

```
1. git add . 
2. git reset HEAD preserve.css
3. git commit -m "The message you want"
4. git push remote_name branch
```